# Does AWS policy block all operations not specified in the policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, policy

For example,

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "ExamplePolicy01",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ExampleStatement01",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/Dave"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket1/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket1"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This policy allows Dave to execute 3 operations to *awsexamplebucket1* in S3. Then how about another operations like creating objects in *awsexamplebucket1?* Are those operations blocked or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the [Policy Evaluation Logic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html). All other actions are implicitly denied. This means that are denied, unless there is another policy that allows them.

Copying from the link above:

> The following is a summary of the AWS evaluation logic for policies
> within a single account.
>
> - By default, all requests are implicitly denied with the exception of the AWS account root user, which has full access.
> - An explicit allow in an identity-based or resource-based policy overrides this default.
> - If a permissions boundary, Organizations SCP, or session policy is present, it might override the allow with an implicit deny.
> - An explicit deny in any policy overrides any allows.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and documentation link!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Dave is an IAM User in the same account as this S3 bucket, typically you would assign these permissions to Dave directly (via policies attached to the Dave IAM User or one of his IAM Groups). You would *not* do this in the S3 bucket policy.

In answer to your question, no this bucket policy doesn't block other, non-listed operations on the bucket. But, by default, no other permissions exist.

If, however, Dave had additional S3 permissions related to this bucket from his IAM User or IAM Group policies then those would supplement the permissions listed in the bucket policy.